# Using awk how do I combine data in two files and substitute values from the second file to the first file?

Tags: awk, calculated-columns, multiplication

Any ideas how to the following using awk?

Two input files, data.txt and keys.txt:

data.txt contains some data:

```
A;1
B;2
A;3
```

keys.txt contains "key;value" pairs ("C" is in this example not part of data.txt, but the awk script should still work):

```
A;30
B;20
C;10
```

The output should be as follows:

```
A;1;30
B;2;20
A;3;30
```

Hence, each row in data.txt that contains any key from keys.txt should get the corresponding value appended to the row in data.txt.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. If you have attempted to write something and have some difficulties, then show what you have done and ask a specific question.
Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips. If you just want free work done then StackOverflow isn't the place for such requests.
Learn to write your code yourself or pay someone to write it for you.

Comment: asked and answered a million times on this site, poke around....

Comment: why last output is not `A;3;30`?

Comment: @karakfa You are correct, my fault. Updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

assumes the second file has unique keys unlike first file (if not you need to specify what happens then)

```
$ awk 'BEGIN   {FS=OFS=";"} 
       NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
       $1 in a {print $0,a[$1]}' file2 file1

A;1;30
B;2;20
A;3;30
```

ps. note the order of files...

Comment: @karafka thanks for the reply, it is not exactly the output I was after, I updated the original question in order to try to make it more precise.

Comment: If you can't describe the problem, it's futile to look for an answer...

Comment: @karafka In case there is no key in keys.txt that matches some of the rows in data.txt, how would you append a default value of "1" for those rows in data.txt?

Comment: I think this question was beaten to death with modifications and won't get any more attention.  I would suggest you write up a new question with the cases you want to cover.

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}{if($1 in a) $0=$0 FS a[$1]; print}' file2 file1
```

The output:

```
A1;1;2
A2;2;1
A3;3;0.5
A1;1;2
A2;2;1
A3;3;0.5
```

---

- `NR==FNR` - processing the first file i.e. `file2`
- `a[$1]=$2` - accumulating additional values for each *key*
- `if($1 in a) $0=$0 FS a[$1]` - appending value if first column matches

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, it does not work completely, I clarified the original question.

Comment: @Markus, I don't see problem there. The output is as in your question. Check if you hadn't made any typos or you may have confused the order of files

Comment: yes thanks, the output was correct according to the question, but I made a minimalistic example. For larger data ( I just updated the original question with a little more data) I don't get the awk solution to work.

Comment: @Markus, have you seen the output in my answer?

Comment: yes, thanks, I tried it with the updated data in my question, but it does not produce correct output. Any ideas?

Comment: @Markus, why do you change your data every time? That's not good

Comment: agreed, data should ideally not change in the original question, the reason is to try to improve the "readability" of my question since I got the feeling I was not communicating the question clearly enough. My apologies for this. However the question is still the same, although with different words.