# Using awk, conditionally print default value based on key,value not existing in second file

Tags: awk, printing, conditional-statements, default, key-value

This is a variant on 
[Using awk how do I combine data in two files and substitute values from the second file to the first file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111737/using-awk-how-do-i-combine-data-in-two-files-and-substitute-values-from-the-seco)

The reason this question is not the same as the one linked above is that this one handles a couple of additional cases.

data.txt contains some data:

```
A;1
B;2
C;3
A;4
```

keys.txt contains "key,value" pairs, however, the key,value pair for C is missing:

```
A;60
B;50
D;30
```

Desired output

```
A;1;60
B;2;50
C;3;1
A;4;60
```

For all "key,value" pairs missing, append default value of 1 to those rows. Should also be able to handle "key,value" pairs in keys.txt which doesn't have a corresponding key in data.txt (such as D;30 in this example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using awk how do I combine data in two files and substitute values from the second file to the first file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111737/using-awk-how-do-i-combine-data-in-two-files-and-substitute-values-from-the-seco)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

compared to the related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44114701/1435869)
remove in filter and replace last field with a conditional.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN   {FS=OFS=";"}
       NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}
               {print $0,($1 in a)?a[$1]:1}' file2 file1

A;1;60
B;2;50
C;3;1
A;4;60
```