# Using awk how do I combine data in two files and substitute multiple values from the second file to the first file?

Tags: awk, multiple-columns, key-value, substitution

This question is an extension to [Using awk how do I combine data in two files and substitute values from the second file to the first file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111737/using-awk-how-do-i-combine-data-in-two-files-and-substitute-values-from-the-seco)

data.txt contains some data:

```
A;1
B;2
A;3
```

keys.txt contains "key;value1;value;value3;value4" ("C" is in this example not part of data.txt, but the awk script should still work):

```
A;30;BC;100;1000
B;20;CD;200;2000
C;10;DE;300;3000
```

Wanted output:

```
A;1;30;BC;100;1000
B;2;20;CD;200;2000
A;3;30;BC;100;1000
```

Hence, each row in data.txt that contains any key from keys.txt should get the corresponding values appended to the row in data.txt.

Comment: What is the logic for the last line?  Is it based on position (being 3rd line in both files).  It cannot be by keys since there is no "C" in first file.

Comment: @karakfa , you are absolutely correct, my mistake.. corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's similar to the previous answer referred in the question.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN   {FS=OFS=";"} 
       NR==FNR {k=$1; $1=""; a[k]=$0; next} 
       $1 in a {print $0 a[$1]}' file2 file1

A;1;30;BC;100;1000
B;2;20;CD;200;2000
A;3;30;BC;100;1000
```